# Ctrl+A key (sellect all) doesnt work in Ubuntu 19.04 GoogleChrome

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04, browser

Only ctrl+ A key doesn't work. When I'm trying to select all the text using Ctrl+A key in GoogleChrome browser - nothing happens. It seems like I have default settings in ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: It works for me. Does it work for other apps like Firefox and gedit?

Comment: It doesn't work in firefox, gedit, chrome. But works in chromium.

Comment: You could look in the desktop settings whether you have maybe overridden the "CTRL-a" shortcut.

Comment: I have reset all the shortcuts but it still doest work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with theming. I've changed my theme to default and everything is fine right now.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Default"
```